# How to directly judge whether there is any error when Double performs decimal operation?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

It is known that most of the decimals cannot be completely represented by Double, and there is a mistake in computing decimals.

Is there a way to quickly determine whether the decimal operation has errors or not, is it equal to another decimal?

If not, need to calculate by hand. When the analog computer operation converts the number to binary to 53 bits, how do you judge whether you need to carry it?
Searching for .Net seems to use rounding up to 50%, how is this rule implemented in binary?

What I need is not the solution to the decimal error, but how to determine whether there are errors and equality in the decimal operation.

Because it is a paper competition, I hope that I can have a quick hand calculation method! thank!

for example:

Execute the following Visual Basic program fragment and output the result as "True"
Console.WriteLine(1.1 + 1.2 = 2.3)

Execute the following Visual Basic program fragment and output the result as "False"
Console.WriteLine(0.3 - 0.2 = 0.1)

P.S If there is a description, please forgive me, I am not an English speaker.

Comment: Just for the record; are you asking us to come up for an answer that you can use in a competition?

Comment: This is not as easy or trivial as you might imagine. also there is more than one question here

Comment: Please [edit] the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: But this appears on the subject test.. Attach the original question.


"""""22. Execute the following Visual Basic program fragment, what is the output? (A) 1 (B) 0 (C) True (D) False

Console.WriteLine (1.1 + 1.2 = 2.3)""""""

Comment: @Cliff. Then run it and find out. Why are you asking us? https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: @mjwills I tried. I have tried a lot of problems that may arise. However, this does not guarantee that he can test the questions he has. This is the mock test that was released before the test.

Answer (score 1):

Verification of floating point arithmetic with base 2 (binary) is quite complicated topic.

Check out [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) by David Goldberg for the general discussion on issues with floating point representations.

More accessible explanations are available at [The Floating-Point Guide](https://floating-point-gui.de/).

Check out [Floating Point in .NET](https://www.extremeoptimization.com/resources/Articles/FPDotNetConceptsAndFormats.aspx) for description of floating point arithmetic implementation in .NET.

[The pitfalls of verifying floating-point computations](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00128124v5/document) looks into the topic of verification:

> Many of the issues that we discuss here are known to floating-point arithmetic
>   experts. However, they have often been ignored or misunderstood by designers
>   of programming languages, compilers, verification techniques and program
>   analysers. Some of them were taken care of, at least partially, in the
>   definition of Java and the latest standard for C, as well as modern hardware
>   implementations. Our primary objective, however, is to educate the designers
>   of verification systems, who in general do not have the luxury to change the
>   hardware implementation, the programming language, the compilers used or
>   the algorithms of the systems that they have to verify.

Comment: Thanks in advance.I hope to have a quick hand calculation or judgment method. If I don't have it, I will hardly read these files.